# Unable to access express/node server on port 3001 despite enabling via firewall-cmd

Tags: node.js, express, firewall, iptables

I've been searching around this morning trying to figure out how to resolve my issue but nothing appears to suit my situation or solve my problem and so here I am.

I have a server running on `CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)` and I have installed node v10.11.0 in order to host a website. I have a domain `foo.ca` whereby I have two separate web servers running (one for client, one for server). The client runs on port 3000, and  I used iptables to forward port 80 to port 3000 so I can actually view my website without explicitly listing the port (i.e. by entering `foo.ca` in the address bar)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

This works fine, and I can see `foo.ca`

My problem arises when I try to access the server which is running on port 3001. I have enabled the port via tcp using firewall-cmd:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3001/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

If I type `foo.ca:3001` chrome tells me the site can't be reached, `foo.ca` took too long to respond.

I tested port 3001 via an online tool and it says that it is open, I also checked netstat:

```
netstat -tuplen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      995        12161      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          12066      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       56647615   4926/node
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       56671635   6195/node
```

Some online suggestions included using `0.0.0.0` rather than localhost but as you can see I already have that implemented. I don't really know what my options are at this point, I've tried enabling the port via iptables as well but I am not sure that did anything:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3001 -j ACCEPT
```

One last thing, my express server code is like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

And I run it like `node test`

Anyone have any ideas? I'm not much of a network guru

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Comment: Can you access the site from the machine itself where it is hosted by using curl http://localhost:3001?

Comment: and can you access the site with just the ip address and port combination like http://192.168.1.6:3001?

Comment: You don't have to configure iptables to redirect the traffic. You can just configure two virtual host in apache one for server (server.foo.ca) and one for client(client.foo.ca) and you are all good.

Comment: Try this link https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf59/using-apache-with-virtual-hosts-and-mod_proxy-792499654.html

Comment: After virtual host configuration check the changes by making the entry in host file. If all is good then you can make the DNS entry

Comment: Sorry just saw these comments, give me a minute to prepare a reply

Comment: @ManishR yes I can curl from the local machine and get the correct response

Comment: Also I am using Node, not apache

Comment: Yes I know you are using node

Comment: Try to implement what I suggested. In case of any query just post it here

Comment: But you see I don't want to use Apache, not now, not ever

Comment: In that case you will have to access second site via port i.e., http://x.x.x.x:3001

Comment: Yes, but I am ok with this

Comment: what do you get when you ping foo.ca? Is it private address or public address?

Comment: It is public address, I get timed out request though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181766/discussion-between-manish-r-and-dave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was my network was blocking it for some reason